# Assign more than one result to a mysql variable

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a procedure and I need to set the value of a variable the result of one query. That query returns more than one value and Mysql throws the error 1242 subquery returns more than 1 row. I need to save the result in a variable like an array and then use that variable like parameter in other procedure. This is the code I have.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getCodes()
    BEGIN
        @code=(SELECT codref FROM referee WHERE town='Malaga');
        CALL getMatch(@code);
    END;$$
```

Comment: Do you want to call the `getMatch` for that many number of times the `select codref ...` returns?

Comment: No, I want to call it once. If arrays exists in mysql it'll be easy because I want to use the variable like an array

Comment: Mysql doesn't do table valued functions as far as I'm aware. Not enough info to help you further. Need to know what getMatch does.

Comment: @temerariomalaga: Then no, you can't assign set of values fetched from a result set to a variable directly. You have to use cursors and read one by one. And use them to pass the other SP. Otherwise again, you may need a change in `getMatch` SP. But for that to say, one needs to understand what `getMatch` is doing?

Comment: getMatch do a other query and I use the code variable in the where clause. getMatch do this: SELECT date, hour from MATCH WHERE referee=@code;

Comment: @Ravinder I will try to use a cursor for do this and insert the result into a temporaly table. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `getMatch` seems to fetch records based on a single `referee` value. Then from `getCodes()` SP you can only pass one value to `getMatch` SP, but not an array of values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `CURSOR` for iteration:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getCodes ()
BEGIN
DECLARE code int;
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT coderef FROM referee WHERE town='Malaga';
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

OPEN cur1;
REPEAT
 FETCH cur1 INTO code;
 IF NOT done THEN
  CALL getMatch(code);
 END IF;
 UNTIL done END REPEAT;
 CLOSE cur1;
END;
```

See MySQL [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html) for details.